# genus two surface symmetry question

Tags: general-topology

How would I embed a genus two surface in space so that it has three fold symmetry? I have a hard time visualizing 3 dimensional topology although it is even harder for me to draw.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine three lines of longitude on a unit sphere (embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$), at angles 0, $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, and $\frac{4\pi}{3}$. Let $G$ be the union of those three lines of longitude. Then $G$ has three-fold rotational symmetry, and the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that are distance exactly $\frac{1}{4}$ from $G$ form a genus 2 surface.

I found a picture of something like this [here](http://www.unhyperbolic.org/research/R2_2.jpg).

Comment: Hmm interesting. Question. Is it possible to embed a genus two surface in space so as to admit symmetry of order 8 or order 10?

Comment: I would expect not. Let $M$ be the genus two surface, $\varphi$ an automorphism of $M$ of order $n$ (where probably $n=8$ or $n=10$. Let me suppose that $\varphi$ has an even finite number  $2d$ of fixed points, and that $M/\varphi$ is an orientable manifold (I think this will necessarily be the case if $M$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\varphi$ comes from an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$). If $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic of $M/\varphi$, then Riemann-Hurwitz says $d=\frac{2+n\chi}{2(n-1)}$. Since $\chi\in\{2,0,-2,-4,\ldots\}$, $d$ can only be a positive integer for $n\leq 3$.

Comment: @SteveThomas: Pink Elephants gave you a perfect answer to your original question. If you have more questions, you should consider accepting his/her/their answer and posting other questions separately.

Comment: Note that both the original an the follow up questions are problem 1.2.6 of Thurston's great book "Three dimensional geometry and topology"